# Polynomial Function from $R^n$ to $R^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, terminology, fixed-point-theorems

what means please a Polynomial Function from $R^n$ to $R^n$,i find this expression when i was seeing the proof of Brouwer fixed point ([page 38 ,line 5](https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/~ledret/M2Elliptique/chapitre1.pdf))
Thank you ,

Comment: It means maps sending $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ to $(P_1(x_1,\ldots ,x_n),\ldots, P_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n))$. The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Probabiy a polynomial in several variables for each coordinate, like
$$
f(x,y) = (x^2y + 2y + 1, x + y^{13})
$$
mapping $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself.

(The link you posted doesn't work for me so I can't check.)

Comment: @YoussefSabar The link works now but it goes to Chapter 5 and there's no page 38.

Comment: I think you can check now please ,i want to apply the Stone-Weirstarss theorem on a continuous function from $\overline{B^m}$ to $R^m$,Weirstarss applies on continous functions from caompacte space to $R$

Comment: https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/~ledret/M2Elliptique/chapitre1.pdf